# How to convert javascript to jquery + use it in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have written the following (working) javascript

```
function calc(A,B,SUM) { 
  var one = Number(A); 
  var two = Number(document.getElementById(B).value);  
  if (isNaN(one)) { alert('Invalid entry: '+A); one=0; } 
  if (isNaN(two)) { alert('Invalid entry: '+B); two=0; } 
  document.getElementById(SUM).value = (one/(((two*0.6)/2.4)/12))*100; 
}
```

However, I need to convert it to jquery to work with Wordpress. I have a .js file properly enqueued.

Everything I do just creates errors. What resources are out there to explain how to convert it to jquery and how to make they jquery work in wordpress?

Comment: You don't have to convert it to jQuery, jQuery is javascript, and the code should work perfectly fine in Wordpress.

Comment: It works fine outside of WP and I thought in the past I remember something about needing to do something special.

Comment: Yes unless you have too much cross-browser problems or no animations needed, stick with javascript code, which would be faster, as internally jQuery converts the code to javascript.

Comment: I am not a javascript guy by any means, but it works in my code editor and jsfiddle. The script is loading on the Wordpress page properly as I can see it via the code inspector . . . so as it's written is should work on a Wordpress page?

Comment: Hey Jason, jQuery is facade to javascript, the library based on javascript, created to ease the development process for developers by giving easy and simple APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with javascript unless jQuery is needed. Otherwise below is equivalent jQuery code.

```
function calc(A,B,SUM) { 
  var one = Number(A), two = Number($("#"+B).val());  
  if (isNaN(one)) { alert('Invalid entry: '+A); one=0; } 
  if (isNaN(two)) { alert('Invalid entry: '+B); two=0; } 
  $("#"+SUM).value = (one/(((two*0.6)/2.4)/12))*100; 
}
```